# How can we invoke the parent's method, when a child has a method with the same name in JavaScript? Anything like type casting in Java here?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, casting

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    present() {
        return `I have a ${this.x}`;
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }

    present() {
        return `${super.present()}, it is a ${this.y}`;
    }
}


child = new Child("Tinggu", "Winggu");
console.log(child.present()); // invokes the child version
```

How would I invoke the parent's method, from the child object? Type-Casting like Java doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you mean `present()` instead of  `parent()` in the `Child` class ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a parent method from child class in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854958/how-to-call-a-parent-method-from-child-class-in-javascript)

Comment: @TimVN NO... it doesn't help me! Sorry.

Comment: You are not or you don't want to?
`Parent.prototype.present.call(this)` would achieve what you want.

Comment: @TimVN The `prototype` concept is completely foreign to me. So I did not understand the link that you provided.

Comment: However, when presented properly to a newbie... It does begin to make sense. Just like @adiga did below. Much appreciated.

Comment: Understandable. Check out this link to get a better understanding of this concept: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods inside the class get added to `Parent.prototype`. So, you could [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the Parent's `present` function with the child object as `this`

```
Parent.prototype.present.call(child)
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    present() {
        return `I have a ${this.x}`;
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(x, y) {
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }

    present() {
        return `${super.present()}, it is a ${this.y}`;
    }
}

const child = new Child("Tinggu", "Winggu");
console.log(
  Parent.prototype.present.call(child)
);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... also worth pointing out that if this needs to be done frequently, you can `const present = Parent.prototype.present.call.bind(Parent.prototype.present); present(child);`

Comment: However, this concept of `prototype` is completely new to me. Can you pint me to any introductory articles on the internet that will help me understand this better?

Comment: @Grateful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes